# find docs by a id field that not exists given document's nested field that contains ids

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, search-engine

i have a int id field and a nested int array ids field on my docs. i want to find docs based an id field that not exists in the given document's id list.

Example:

```
[{
   my_id: 1,
   other_ids: [2,3]
},{
   my_id: 2,
   other_ids: [1]
},{
   my_id: 3,
   other_ids: [2]
}]
```

ty.

Comment: i.e. do you want to retrieve documents without the value `3` in `other_ids`? Do you have an example query and which documents you want to return?

Comment: For example: i want to search for docs that my_id not in other_ids that doc with my_id:3. and result must be the doc that my_id:1